# Asymptotic growth of $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^\alpha}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

Let $0 < \alpha < 1$. Can somebody please explain why
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^\alpha} \sim n^{1-\alpha}$$
holds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compare with the integral 
$$\int_1^n \frac{dx}{x^\alpha}.$$

Comment: This falls short of showing why this is the _dominant_ contribution. Or is it obvious?

Comment: @Sasha: One actually wants inequalities that use two closely related integrals. But I thought something should be left for the OP to do.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that is what Davide has done in his answer. While you're at it, could you please have a look at a somewhat [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208152/estimate-a-sum-of-products) of mine?

Answer (score 7):

We have for $x\in [k,k+1)$ that $$(k+1)^{—\alpha}\leq x^{-\alpha}\leq k^{—\alpha},$$
and integrating this we get 
$$(k+1)^{—\alpha}\leq \frac 1{1-\alpha}((k+1)^{1-\alpha}-k^{\alpha})\leq k^{—\alpha}.$$
We get after summing and having used $(n+1)^{1-\alpha}-1\sim n^{1-\alpha}$, the equivalent $\frac{n^{1-\alpha}}{1-\alpha}$.