# Finding the nth sum of a series

Tags: summation, power-series

I am to find the sum of a series that takes this format

$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i^\beta}
$

$
\beta  
$
is a positive real number

How to approach the partial sum of the above series and can obtain its estimation as below

$
\approx\frac{n^{1-\beta}}{1-\beta}
$

Thanks a lot for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:compare with the integral $$\int_1^n \frac{dx}{x^\beta}.$$

Comment: your post reminds me of this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/208830

Comment: @311411 It’s really an old question